# Setting Custom metadata to an object in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, gsutil

I have an android app that uploads files to a storage bucket in Firebase Storage. When it does, it adds the custom metadata `userId`.
When I upload files from my computer using `gsutil` with the following command from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#custom-metadata):

```
gsutil -h x-goog-meta-userId:<userId> cp my_file gs://bucket/folder
```

It adds the metadata but it changes the capital **`I`** for a small **`i`**.

Is there something to do, so that the metadata keeps the capitalization?

I have a function that relies on finding the metadata as `userId`, otherwise it returns `null`, my workaround at the moment is to check for both `userId` and `userid`. But moving forward is good to know if that is better to set the metadata key in small letters only.
This is very inconvenient when copying from bucket to bucket as it will add an extra custom metadata instead of replacing the appropriate one.

Comment: Actually I was able to add a [custom key with an uppercase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVMsK.png) via console but not using the command. I'm investigating more on this

Comment: @Chris32 And I could do it from an Android app, seems like might be a problem with `gsutil`. Before posting here I checked their GitHub and seems like there was a similar issue [#421](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/421) before but it was fixed in an update. although in the issue the OP was using `setmeta`.

Comment: Yes, there was an update that fixed this in the past but now this is reoccuring. For the moment there is no update. As a workaround if a custom key case sensitive is needed you can just manually add ity using the console. Gsutil is keeping the value case sensitive so this is only required for custom key's.

Comment: For the moment, I'm already covered, but moving forward I think is there should be consistency across APIs. It took me sometime to debug my issue because among other things I had to choose an `I` to capitalize :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage's XML API [uses HTTP headers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgoogmeta) to expose and set custom object metadata. Per [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), HTTP headers are case insensitive, and so while you can specify case with the other APIs, we generally discourage relying on it.

That said, I agree that the existing gsutil behavior is likely a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend you to use upper case in metadata (and in headers in general). I received an email, months ago, and I found a copy in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/rS_2v6bTaVo/pCRQcYE7DAAJ)

Google transform all headers in lowercase. Thereby, get the habit today to use lower case header for all your API calls.